# How to change the port number of Apache in Xampp

Tags: apache, xampp, port

I am  a novice I do not know anything about port numbers and how to change them. While installing Xampp on my windows 8.1 it is showing Error in port  that apache has to use. How can I resolve this port issue and which port number I should change it to
Please help me out
[This is the error coming while  running xampp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsC9r.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open xamp, click on http.conf and search `ServerName localhost`

```
 ServerName localhost:8181
```

I have set 8181 as my port, it will be 80 change it to 81 (since 80 is being used VMware in your case and it is used by skype too).

Reset the server after saving it..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue. For an example Developers can run `Java` web applications on `JBoss server` and at the same time test `PHP` project on `XAMMP server`. To make both servers up and carry out developments, port numbers need to be changed. Following is the way for changing port number in `XAMMP Server`.

If the `XAMPP server` is running for the moment, stop XAMPP server.

**Follow these steps to change the port number.**

Open the file in following location.

```
[XAMPP Installation Folder]/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

Open the `httpd.conf` file and search for the String:

**Listen 80**

This is the port number used by XAMMP.

Then search for the string **ServerName** and update the **Port Number** which you entered earlier for `Listen`

***Now save and re-start XAMPP server.***