# I can't change xampp apache default port number

Tags: php, apache, xampp, port, httpd.conf

I changed the httpd.conf file lines:

`Listen 80` TO `Listen 8012`

`servername localhost`  TO `servername localhost:8012`

And still it trys to start apache at port 80, but can't because a system process is using it.

**EDIT**
No my question is still different because I already followed those steps listed in the possible duplicate question: [How to change the port number of Apache in Xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552306/how-to-change-the-port-number-of-apache-in-xampp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the port number of Apache in Xampp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552306/how-to-change-the-port-number-of-apache-in-xampp)

Comment: @dparoli - no please read my edit section.

Comment: look at this other one please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port

Comment: @dparoli your a genius lol.  Please add as answer so people realize not only to change the httpd.conf file and to also change to different port in the http-ssl file.

Comment: thants @coderg but this is your answer, I didnt know anything about it I only point you in the right direction. Add the steps you follow to solve the problem and XAMPP version for those with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run xampp as an Administrator. it will fix it.